# Зачем возвращать что-либо из методов?

Tags: java, ооп

Зачем мы в методах вообще что-либо возвращаем? Переменная ведь и так в себе будет содержать результат, зачем его еще возвращать то? Не совсем понимаю, вот например вырванный из контекста:

```
int a = scan.nextInt();
int b = scan.nextInt();
int result = a + b;
return result;
```

Comment: Если вам не требуется что-либо возвращать - просто ничего не возвращайте да и всё

Comment: У меня встречный вопрос: а как вы представляете себе систему где ничто ничего не возвращает? А так да, **всегда возвращать не нужно**. Только когда надо

Comment: Очень просто, result и так в себе содержит результат a и b, зачем туда его ещё возвращать?

Comment: окей и что с этим result вы будете делать?

Comment: Функции или методы это инкапсуляция кода в некоторую структуру, чтоб вызывать её когда нужно и сколько нужно. Результат работы этого фрагмента кода и выводится с помощью return, когда это нужно разумеется

Comment: Вычисление завершается или возвращаемым результатом или побочным эффектом. Иногда и тем и другим. Если нет ни того ни другого, вычисление бесполезно. В зависимости от контекста и архитектуры вы решаете что вам ближе - побочные эффекты или возвращаемые результаты.

Comment: Если в вашем примере вы не вернёте результат, он пропадёт, как пропадают все локальные переменные когда метод или функция завершаются.

Comment: Вы заказали бургер. Его сделали - result готов. Но вам не отдали - return ведь не нужен... В Pascal в функциях есть псевдопеременная Result (в старом просто имя функции такую роль выполняло) - там не надо return, компилятор обеспечит передачу значения вызывающему коду. А в Java надо.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: переменная-то содержать будет. Вот только где вы эту переменную за пределами метода возьмете?

Comment: затем что методы и функции не для хранения данных предназначены, а для их вычисления. для хранения есть свойства, массивы, объекты, БД. +инициализировать какие либо переменные внутри функции так себе идея ибо, вне неё они в большинстве вменяемого кода не должны быть доступны из-за инкапсуляции(в php это конечно можно обойти объявлением глобалок, но само по себе их использование та еще клиника). в нормальном коде результат не требуется возвращать только если он утилизируется(применяется по назначению) прямо внутри функции `function x($x){$y=1; echo $x + $y;}` а это скорее исключение из правил

Comment: MBo лучший, спасибо Вам)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мы вызываем метод(функцию) чтобы получить какой-то результат.
return возвращает результат работы метода и/или завершает работу метода.

если написать

```
public void method(){
    return;
}
```

ide тебе напишет что команда `return;`  в методе с возвращаемым типом `void` избыточна, в этом случае `return;`  завершает работу метода. т.е. каждый метод неявно заканчивается return;

другой пример, в зависимости от переданного параметра мы возвращаем определённое сообщение

```
public class Main {
    public static String select(int number) {
        if (number > 10) return "больше 10";
        if (number < 0) return "меньше 0";
        else return "0";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(select(0)); // 0
        System.out.println(select(11)); // больше 10
        System.out.println(select(-1)); // меньше 0
    }
}
```

хороший пример написал МВо про бургеры, ты у электронного болвана вызываешь метод оформить заказ, выбираешь на экране входящие параметры - кола, бургер, картошка и при нажатии оплатить оформляешь заказ, т.е. данный метод возвращает(делает return) твоего заказа с определённым номером на кухню, как-то так...

Comment: При написании кода Java нужно как минимум избегать хардкода. Для этого создаются переменные и константы, и перечисления enum.

Comment: @Roman C я попытался простыми словами и примерами объяснить принцип работы return

Comment: В данном случае оператор return используется для возврата значения из метода, а не для его завершения. Знание как работает return полезно но это не отвечает на вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

> Зачем мы в методах вообще что либо возвращаем?

Ну если метод объявлен как функция, то есть должен возвращать значение, то это обязательно.

> Переменная ведь и так в себе будет содержать результат, зачем его еще возвращать то?

Переменная `result` - это автономная переменная, которая оптимизируется компилятором с использованием регистров. Время жизни такой переменной измеряется внутри блока или метода, в котором она объявлена, а ее значение возвращается в место вызова этого метода. Результат вычислений, который присваивается этой переменной виден только в блоке, где эта переменная создана. Создание дополнительных переменных в коде полезно для того, чтобы придать коду наглядность и облегчить отладку. В других случаях она бесполезна, текущий код можно переписать так

```
int a = scan.nextInt();
int b = scan.nextInt();
return a + b;
```

Возвращать или не возвращать значение из метода определяется его сигнатурой. Если мы хотим сохранить результат вычислений то, существует множество способов это сделать. Например мы можем использовать другие объекты и методы. Эти объекты должны быть доступны в методе, или являются переменными класса, или передаются с помощью параметров, и т.д.

---

Вот что по этому поводу написано в [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html):

**Возврат значения из метода:**
Метод возвращается к коду, который его вызвал, когда он

- завершает все операторы в методе,
- достигает оператора возврата, или
- выдает исключение (рассмотрено позже),
  в зависимости от того, что произойдет первым.

Вы объявляете возвращаемый тип метода в его объявлении метода.  В теле метода вы используете оператор `return` для возврата значения.

Любой метод, объявленный как `void`, не возвращает значение.  Он не обязательно должен содержать оператор возврата, но он может его содержать.  В таком случае можно использовать оператор `return` для выхода из блока потока управления и выхода из метода, и он просто используется следующим образом:

- возвращаться;
  Если вы попытаетесь вернуть значение из метода, который объявлен как `void`, вы получите ошибку компилятора.

Любой метод, который не объявлен как `void`, должен содержать оператор `return` с соответствующим возвращаемым значением, например:

- вернуть возвращаемое значение;
  Тип данных возвращаемого значения должен соответствовать объявленному типу возвращаемого значения метода;  вы не можете вернуть целочисленное значение из метода, объявленного для возврата логического значения.

Метод `getArea()` в классе `Rectangle`, который обсуждался в разделах, посвященных объектам, возвращает целое число:

```
// метод вычисления площади прямоугольника
        
public int getArea() {
        return width * height;
}
```

Этот метод возвращает целое число, которое оценивается выражением ширина*высота.

Метод `getArea()` возвращает примитивный тип.  Метод также может возвращать ссылочный тип.  Например, в программе для управления объектами `Bicycle` у нас может быть такой метод:

```
public Bicycle seeWhosFastest(Bicycle myBike, Bicycle yourBike,
                              Environment env) {
    Bicycle fastest;
    // code to calculate which bike is 
    // faster, given each bike's gear 
    // and cadence and given the 
    // environment (terrain and wind)
    return fastest;
}
```

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.