# Логика выполнения вызванного метода при передаче параметра

Tags: java, методы, передача-параметров

Никак не могу понять логику выполнения метода: до функции `main` мы создаём метод `test1`, который инкрементирует `int a` на единицу.
После функции `main` мы прописываем значение для `int a`, и обращаемся к ранее созданному методу `test1`.

Из-за того, что Java передаёт параметры по значению, результат в методе до `main` будет равен `11`, а после - `10`. Но разве метод, вызываемый после `main` не должен также инкрементировать переданное ему значение? Почему он просто оставляет значение `10`? Ведь это один и тот же метод...

```
static void test1(int a) {
    a++;
    System.out.printf("test 1 a = %d", a);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        int a=10;
        test1(a);
        System.out.printf("a=%d", a);
    }
}
```

Comment: нет никакого "до метода мейн" или "после метода мейн", методы живут в одной куче все рядом. Также параметр а в методе тест никак не связан с переменной а в методе мейн. Можете переменну вася назвать, параметр петя, а в функцию вообще передать 666

Comment: также передача по значению означает передачу копии, то есть вот у вас есть бумажка с надписью 10, вы делаете от неё ксерокопию и эту копию как параметр шлете в метод test, что там с копией случится - останется внутри метода текст и никак не повлияет на вашу оригинальную бумажку.

Comment: Тут вопрос скорее в том, почему вызванный метод "тест" не инкрементирует переданный ему параметр также, как это было при его объявлении. Это ведь один и тот же метод. Тем более Вы сказали, что нет разницы до или после main-а. А вместо этого ему просто передается параметр из интовой переменной и всё. Вот здесь я завис если честно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java нет таких понятий как *до* и *после* с точки зрения объявления методов. Методы в классах могут объявляться в каком угодно порядке, это никак не влияет на их работу.

При этом каждый метод имеет свою *область* *видимости* переменных. Разные методы могут иметь переменные с совершенно одинаковыми именами, но это будут их собственные переменные. В том числе переменные, являющиеся параметрами метода, никак не связаны по именам с переменными, которые будут передаваться из вызывающего метода.

В вашем случае есть метод `test1`:

```
static void test1(int a) {
    a++;
    System.out.printf("test 1 a = %d", a);
}
```

Он имеет параметр `int a`. Это его собственная переменная, он ничего не знает о каких-либо других переменных с именем `a` в других методах. Что на место параметра `a` передастся из вызывающего метода - то этот метод скопирует и с тем будет работать, нарастив на 1 и выведя на экран.

Вызывающим же методом является метод `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=10;
    test1(a);
    System.out.printf("a=%d", a);
}
```

У него есть своя переменная `int a = 10`. Он передаёт её в метод `test1`. Там она копируется и наращивается на 1: в результате получаем переменную `int a = 10` в методе `main` и переменную `int a = 11` в методе `test1`. Затем методом `test1`  его переменная `a` выводится на экран, он заканчивает свою работу, а метод `main` - продолжает, выводя на экран **свою** переменную `a`, равную 10-ти.

Comment: Подскажите - а как же тогда сделать так, чтобы вызываемый метод осуществлял те же действия, что и первоначально объявленный? Я понял, что а=10 находится в области видимости main, но всё равно передается как параметр по значению в test1. С этим - ок. Но в test1 он инкрементируется, а в main уже нет. Разве у объявленного, и, позже вызванного метода не должен быть единый функционал?

Comment: Любой метод при вызове осуществляет ровно те действия, которые в нём заложены при объявлении. Метод `test1` копирует переменную `a`, наращивает её (то есть копию!) на 1 и выводит на экран. На этом его работа честно заканчивается. Мы возвращаемся в `main`, который продолжает оперировать _своей_ переменной `a`, которая была и остаётся равной 10-ти.

Comment: Если же вы хотите, чтобы результат наращивания переменной в методе `test1` не терялся, то можете объявить метод `test1` возвращающим значение `int` и написать в его конце `return a;`, а в методе `main` сделать вызов `a = test1(a);`. В таком случае, переменная `a` в `main` станет равной 11-ти после отработки `test1`. Подробнее про возврат значения из методов написано в ответах Nowhere Man и Roman C.

Comment: То есть метод [tag: main} первоначально не инкрементировал значение переменной [tag: a] только потому, что из-за [tag: void-а] данный метод попросту не обязан был что-либо возвращать (а следовательно и что-либо считать), верно же понял?

Comment: Нет, он обязан нарастить переменную, так как это его работа. Но наращивает он копию переменной из `main`. Так как он `void` - то да, результат не возвращает, но наращивание происходит (наращивание копии!). Вы ведь в этом методе делаете вывод на экран, так что совершенно точно должны видеть вывод "11". А по окончании работы метода `test1` метод `main` продолжает свою работу, оперируя переменной `a`, равной 10, так как для него она не поменялась, и не должна была. Как я уже сказал, хотите отразить этот результат в `main` - сделайте в нём вызов `a = test1(a);`, а функцию `test1` возвращающей int

Comment: Да, коряво последний запрос описал, но кажется я верно понял. Большое спасибо за разъяснение!

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что **параметры методов передаются не по ссылке, а по значению**. Для того чтобы получить новое значение из метода нужно его вернуть оператором `return`. По этому поводу можно посмотреть [Зачем возвращать что-либо из методов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1466517/204920).

Вот что по этому поводу написано в [Java Tutorial](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1466517/204920):

**Возврат значения из метода:**
Метод возвращается к коду, который его вызвал, когда он

- завершает все операторы в методе,
- достигает оператора возврата, или
- выдает исключение (рассмотрено позже),
  в зависимости от того, что произойдет первым.

Вы объявляете возвращаемый тип метода в его объявлении метода.  В теле метода вы используете оператор `return` для возврата значения.

Любой метод, объявленный как `void`, не возвращает значение.  Он не обязательно должен содержать оператор возврата, но он может его содержать.  В таком случае можно использовать оператор `return` для выхода из блока потока управления и выхода из метода, и он просто используется следующим образом:

- возвращаться;
  Если вы попытаетесь вернуть значение из метода, который объявлен как `void`, вы получите ошибку компилятора.

Любой метод, который не объявлен как `void`, должен содержать оператор `return` с соответствующим возвращаемым значением, например:

- вернуть возвращаемое значение;
  Тип данных возвращаемого значения должен соответствовать объявленному типу возвращаемого значения метода;  вы не можете вернуть целочисленное значение из метода, объявленного для возврата логического значения.

---

Чтобы метод возвращал значение код можно переписать так:

```
static int test1(int a) {
    a++;
    System.out.printf("test 1 a = %d", a);
    return a;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        int a=10;
        a = test1(a);
        System.out.printf("a=%d", a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае в качестве аргумента передаётся *примитивное* целочисленное значение переменной `a` (локальной для метода `main`), то есть при вызове метода `test1` в стек записывается копия целого числа (аргумента метода), внутри метода эта копия считывается из стека и все модификации этой переменной внутри метода остаются незамеченными снаружи.

Если бы передавалась переменная-объект типа `Integer`, результат был бы такой же, так как класс `Integer` является неизменяемым (*immutable*), то есть его внутреннее состояние нельзя изменить и разным числам 1, 2, .. соответствуют разные экземпляры.

```java
static void test2(Integer a) {
    a++;
    System.out.println("test2: a=" + a);
}

Integer a = 10;
test2(a);
System.out.println("main: a=" + a);
```

```java
test2: a=11
main: a=10
```

То есть здесь в метод через стек передаётся копия ссылки на `Integer(1)`, вследствие инкремента *локальной переменной* `a` внутри метода присваивается другая ссылка на `Integer(2)`, и это изменение никак не затрагивает "внешнюю" локальную переменную `a`.

Чтобы добиться изменения внутри некоего экземпляра класса после вызова метода, необходимо этот класс реализовать соответствующим образом, то есть реализовать класс с полем для хранения состояния и методами для изменения этого состояния:

```java
static class Foo {
    private int x;
    Foo(int x) {this.x = x;}
    public void inc() {this.x++;}
    public void dec() {this.x--;}
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x;}
    public void add(int y) {this.x += y;}
// и т.д.
    public int getX() {return this.x;}
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Foo: x=" + x;
    }
}
```

Тогда при передаче ссылки на экземпляр такого класса и вызове методов-мутаторов состояния внутри некоего метода, эти изменения состояния будут видимы снаружи.

```java
static void test3(Foo f) {
    f.inc();
    System.out.println("test3: f=" + f);
}

Foo f = new Foo(10);
test3(f);
System.out.println("main: f=" + f);
```

Результат:

```java
test3: f=Foo: x=11
main: f=Foo: x=11
```